# Element not found by tagname jasmine and protractor

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc, jasmine, protractor, angular-e2e

My below test always fails as protractor cannot find the element by tag name.

```
it('should show test component',async () => {
    await browser.get('/trade')
    element(by.tagName(('test-component'))).isPresent()
    .then(value=>{
      console.log(value ,'first')
      expect(value).toBeTruthy()
    });

})
```

I have tried the same code in other test spec but it worked. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Mokkasoru Closed as in?

Comment: @Mokkasoru the code here is syntactically correct. I'm not sure what your comment refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code snippet.

```
it('should show test component', async () => {

await browser.get('provide complete url');

var EC = browser.ExpectedConditions;
await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.tagName('test-component'))),10000);

element(by.tagName('test-component')).getText().then(async (value)=>{
console.log(value ,'first')
expect(await value).toBeTruthy();

});
```

Comment: It works, thanks a bunch! Although I would like to know that for each test I need to write so much of code?

Comment: Well, It depends on the structure of your test suite. If you have used proper hooks in your framework than you can handle many repetitive tasks in your hooks and do the test specific tasks in your tests. Otherwise, you need to go with the repetition of your code which is not a good practice.